# Required Assumption for Set Theory Question

Tags: probability, self-study

I have been attempting to solve this set theory question, and am unsure exactly how to answer part b) :

[image: Set Theory Question]

For part a), I got P[A] = 0.4 and P[B] = 0.5. For part b), the only way I can see to solve it is to assume that $P[A \cup B \cup C] = 1$. This is my current working:

$$
\begin{align}
P[B^c] &= 1 - P[B] \\
\therefore P[B^c] &= 1 - 0.5 = 0.5 \\
\\
P[B^c] &= P[A\cup C] - P[B \cap C] - P[A \cap B] \\
\therefore 0.5 &= 0.7 - 0.2 - P[A \cap B] \\
\therefore P[A \cap B] &= 0
\end{align}
$$

Am I correct in my assumption, or is this another way to solve b) without assuming anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is true. Note that
\begin{align}
P(A\cup B\cup C)&=P((A\cup C)\cup( B\cup C))=\\
&=P(A\cup C)+P(B\cup C)-P((A\cup C)\cap(B\cup C))=\\
&=0.7+0.7-P(C)=1
\end{align}
The other calculations are correct.